# How to Close toggle menu when clicking navigation item anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Please see my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ayhpp8ax/)

I've got a 1 page website with a "responsive" navigation menu (with anchor links to elements on the page) that prepends to a menu icon when the browser viewport is smaller than a specific width (in my case 767px) using this javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#menu_wrapper').prepend('<div id="menu-icon">Menu</div>');
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
});
```

As you can see in the fiddle I'm also using javascript to make the navigation sticky when scrolling down past navigation element regardless of the viewport size.

Now the problem I have is that when I am below the viewport of 767px, I click on the toggle 'MENU' button to open / show the navigation and when I click an option in the menu, the page scrolls to the correct part of the page BUT the menu stays open.

What I want is the menu to close (slide back up) when an option is clicked in the menu (obviously this must only apply when I am below below the viewport of 767px).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in $(document).ready function

```
$('#menu li').on('click', function(){
        $("#menu").hide();
        $("#menu-icon").removeClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: Awesome buddy, I tried your solution and it works :) though I had to change $('#menu li') to $('#menu li a') ... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#menu li a').on("click", function(){
    $('#menu').slideUp();
});
```

just `slideUp()` if `#menu li a` is clicked

updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayhpp8ax/1/

Comment: Awesome! thanks ... though when I am in a viewport larger than 767px, you'll notice that my 'normal' menu momentarily disappears when clicking on a category which I obviously don't want (you'll see this in your fiddle)

Comment: I think the slideUp() was causing my menu to momentarily disappear (when in viewport above 767px) which is strange because hide() doesn't cause that problem ... Anyway I still thank you and appreciate your help

Answer (score -2):

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

    var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
      title: "Menu",
      format: "dropdown",
      sticky: false
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        }
        else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          }
          else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($( window ).width() > 1500) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "Menu",
      format: "multitoggle"
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```