# Remove the active class when we click

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, menu

I want to remove the `class="active"` when I click on the element. I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383681/how-to-close-toggle-menu-when-clicking-navigation-item-anchor-link) that we could do something like this:

```
$('#menu li').on('click', function(){
        $("#menu").hide();
        $("#menu-icon").removeClass("active");
    });
```

So with my structure:

[image]

I tried this code :

```
$('.nav side-menu li').on('click', function(){
        $(".nav side-menu li").removeClass("active");
});
```

But nothing happens, what am I doing wrong ?

[EDIT] I think the problems come from the way to select the HTML element
and that's the HTML of the menu:

```
<!-- sidebar menu -->
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
 <div class="menu_section">
  <h3>General</h3>
   <ul class="nav side-menu">
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Docker machines <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav child_menu">
    <li><a class="itemsMenu" href="/">All Docker machines</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Docker containers <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav child_menu">
    <li><a class="itemsMenu" href="/">All containers</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
   <ul class="nav child_menu">
   <li><a class="itemsMenu" href="/dataGraph">Grafana monitoring</a>         </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using Meteor

Comment: Are you missing a '.' in front of `side-menu`?

Comment: Try `$(this).removeClass("active");`

Comment: @G0dsquad it changes nothing :(

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I can't because it use so much others things (custom.js, font-awesome etc...), I means I'm not able to do it

Comment: @Jerome see the other answers below. One of these should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector wont work as you expected, you need to combine them and although use `this` to refer the clicked element.

```
$('.nav.side-menu li').on('click', function(){
   $(this)
     .removeClass("active")
     // get the nested children and hide
     .find('ul') 
     .hide();
});
```

Comment: (i'm not the downvoter) nothing happens with your solution

Comment: @Jerome : is the elements are dynamically generated ?\

Comment: I posted the code in the edit, no it's static and I think the `$('.nav.side-menu li)` doesn't work or it's wrong with my HTML structure

Comment: @Jerome : what are you trying to achieve with the handler ??

Comment: I want to remove the class `active` when I click on the `<li><a class="itemsMenu" href="/">Something</a></li>`

Comment: @Jerome :  where is the active class in that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137941/discussion-between-jerome-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav.side-menu li').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

$('.nav.side-menu li') returns a array of list elements. if you choose it inside the click function you have a array again and it does not work