# Menu from a site doesn’t disappear when I click on an anchor

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my english...
I have a one-page website based on Wordpress.
I put some anchors on my page, but with desktop version, menu closes after I click on a link relative to one of these anchors (or on a normal link).
When I'm on a small screen, the menu doesn't close after clicking on an anchor(with a normal link id does), the page only goes to the anchor but stay invisible because of the menu.
I looked at this subject : [How to Close toggle menu when clicking navigation item anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383681/how-to-close-toggle-menu-when-clicking-navigation-item-anchor-link) but I don't know how could I modify the file to fix it.
This is the code for my menu :

```
/**
 * navigation.js
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens.
 */
( function() {
    var container, button, menu;

    container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
    if ( ! container ) {
        return;
    }

    button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
        return;
    }

    menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );

    if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
        menu.className += ' nav-menu';
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
            container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
        } else {
            container.className += ' toggled';
            button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
        }
    };
} )();
```

Could you tell me how to modify this code to automatically close it after clicking on an anchor? I suppose that the value of "area-expanded" define the state of the menu?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for the page?

Comment: Nothing in your JS refers to an anchor element as far as I can tell, so we will probably need more info to be able to help. Ideally a small reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: The author of the theme I use, ThemeIsle, answered  : they can't  help for the custom work or additional feature not provided in the theme. I noticed the menu dosen't close even in desktop mode with anchors in custom links. I found an issue not so nice : I replaced anchors in custom links by url+ anchors. The problem is pages reload, I lost the scroll.
So i looked at the code posted but I don't know Javascript at all.  maybe anchors should be defined as standard url to allow the closure? Thanks for you future help.